# Error unfortunately navigation drawer intent to other class activity

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

```
 Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new DefaultFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
     }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

When selected case 1 , error show unfortunately app is stopped . But after click "OK" , app will appear MainActivity. How to intent MainActivity without popup 'unfortunately' . Case 0 no problem because DefaultFragment file used extends Fragment.

```
MainActivity File
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DefaultFragment
public class DefaultFragment extends Fragment{
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6hBy.png)

Comment: You need to post the stack trace and more code for us to be certain. I would guess that for `case 1`, you're still trying to perform a `FragmentTransaction` after the `switch`, but `fragment` will be `null`.

Comment: I already edit this question and attach image error when click choose case 1 .

Answer (score 0):

For `case 1`, you're still trying to perform a `FragmentTransaction` after the `switch`, but `fragment` will be `null`. Either `return;` from `case 1`, or move the `FragmentTransaction` to `case 0`.